# "Unfortunately, Google Play Store has stopped" – after installing HTML-only Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I recently developed my first Cordova app for Android, which is very simple, it consists of a big website downloaded for offline browsing using HTTrack (.apk is about 30MB). That's all, and some parts of the webpage I removed manually, so it might have 404s.

Since I installed it, Google Play Store stops at random times. I just get the error messages, without actually using Google Play Store, or my own app, in the middle of something completely different. Not really disturbing, just strange. (This way I won't consider to publicize my app.) After a while, I even cannot access Google Play Store itself. It stops right after searching for a keyword.

Then I restart Android, my app somehow misteriously is uninstalled, and Google Play Store runs fine. Until I install my own app again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial solution found in the meantime: using [Aptoide](https://en.aptoide.com/) instead of Google Play Store. This saves me of restarting device every time before installation. Apparently has the same selection of applications.